# Diff head of files

Tags: diff

I have two files. One file, I suspect, is a subset of the other. Is there a way to diff the files to identify (in a succinct manner) where in the first file the second file fits?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79135/is-there-a-condensed-side-by-side-diff-format/79152#79152

Comment: Do you mean the lines of one file are a subsequence of the other, or actually a contiguous substring?

Comment: A contiguous substring, @Kaz.

Answer (score 14):

`diff -e bigger smaller`  will do the trick, but requires some interpretation, as the output is a "valid ed script".

I made two files, "bigger" and "smaller", where the contents of "smaller" is identical to lines 5 through 9 of "bigger" doing `diff -e bigger smaller" got me:

```
% diff -e bigger smaller
10,15d
1,4d
```

Which means "delete lines 10 through 15 of 'bigger', and then delete lines 1 through 4, to get 'smaller'".  That means "smaller" is lines 5 through 9 of "bigger".

Reversing the file names got me something more complicated. If "smaller" truly constitutes a subset of "bigger", only 'd' (for delete) commands will show up in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this visually with [*meld*](http://meldmerge.org/). Unfortunately, it is a GUI tool but if you just want to do this once, and on a relatively small file, it should be fine:

The image below is the output of `meld a b`:

[image]

Comment: Meld's nice, but it doesn't play quite as well with 100MB+ files.

Comment: @Richard no it doesn't and I would prefer a command line tool anyway, I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Looks a lot like `vimdiff`, which is available in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are small enough, you can slurp them both into Perl and have its regex engine do the trick:

```
perl -0777e '
        open "$FILE1","<","file_1";
        open "$FILE2","<","file_2";
        $file_1 = <$FILE1>;
        $file_2 = <$FILE2>;
        print "file_2 is", $file_1 =~ /\Q$file_2\E/ ? "" : "not";
        print " a subset of file_1\n";
'
```

The `-0777` switch instructs Perl to set its input record separator `$/` to the undefined value so as to slurp files completely.

Comment: What does `777` do? I take it you are passing NULL as `$/` but why? Also since these are kinda esoteric switches, an explanation would be nice for the non-perl people.

Comment: @terdon I am indeed doing it to slurp the files whole. Explanation added.

Comment: But why is that necessary? `$a=<$fh>` should slurp anyway right?

Comment: @terdon Not that I know of, no. By default `$/` is set to `\n` so that `$a=<$fh>` would read only one line of the file `$fh` has been opened to. Unless of course `perl`'s command-line behavior has different defaults that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Argh, yes, my bad, I almost never slurp files or use the `while $foo=<FILE>` idiom so I wasn't sure and ran a (wrong) test which seemed to work. Never mind :).

Comment: @terdon Never slurping files I can understand, but I'd be interested to see how you read your files if you've done away with the `while $foo=<BAR>` idiom as well.

Comment: I use `$_` and a simple `while(<$fh>){}`. And yes, that's the same thing, and no I did not notice and still left a silly comment. Rub it in why don't cha? ;)

Comment: @terdon Oh, so you're still using the `while` idiom, then; only Perlier. :)

Comment: @terdon Nothing's being rubbed in here, I was genuinely interested to see what you were using. In my opinion, (ab)using `$_` is the mark of Perl veterans :)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are text files and `smaller`, within `bigger` starts at the beginning of a line, it's not too difficult to implement with `awk`:

```
awk -v i=0 'NR==FNR{l[n++]=$0;next}
    {if ($0 == l[i]) {if (++i == n) {print FNR-n+1;exit}} else i=0}
    ' smaller bigger
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "Diff head of files".  If you really mean that one file is the head of the other, then a simple `cmp` will tell you that:

```
cmp big_file small_file
cmp: EOF on small_file
```

That tells you that a difference between the two files was not detected until end-of-file was reached while reading `small_file`.

If however you mean that the entire text of small file can occur anywhere inside `big_file`, then assuming you can fit both files in memory, you can use

```
perl -le '
   use autodie;
   undef $/;
   open SMALL, "<", "small_file";
   open BIG, "<", "big_file";
   $small = <SMALL>;
   $big = <BIG>;
   $pos = index $big, $small;
   print $pos if $pos >= 0;
'
```

This will print the offset within `big_file` where the contents of `small_file` are located (e.g. 0 if `small_file` matches at the beginning of `big_file`).  If `small_file` does not match inside `big_file`, then nothing will be printed.  If there is an error, the exit status will be non-zero.