# Side by side diff of large files

Tags: diff

I have two ~1 GB files that I want to do a side by side diff of. Solutions I have tried:

- `diff` - Works quickly but doesn't output side-by-side.
- `diff -y` or `sdiff` - This outputs side-by-side but it outputs the *entire* file - not just the changes, so they are impossible to find.
- [`icdiff`](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff) - Just too slow (it's written in Python so no surprise there).
- [`ydiff`](https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff) - Not actually tried but it is also written in Python so I assume it will also be very slow.
- KDiff3 - Crashed.
- Xcode FileMerge - Too slow (gave it a few minutes of non-responsiveness).
- Beyond Compare - Max 500MB limit.
- Meld - Made a little progress but far too slow to be useful.
- `vimdiff` - Loads the files successfully and actually displays a side-by-side diff, but the colour scheme makes it unreadable, and normal things that you'd expect from a sane program do not work, e.g. pressing up to scroll up.

Comment: Give this Python script a try https://github.com/unhammer/diff-large-files

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch

Answer (score 6):

The best I have so far is:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines --speed-large-files file1 file2
```

Use `--width=200` to control the width.

However unfortunately [that doesn't show you any context lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979187/combine-diff-side-by-side-with-suppress-common-lines-and-context-options).

I found [another solution using `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79137/24186) which seemed ok but it uses a regex and is just too slow.

Comment: This is GNU grep. I'd check it the various context flags work (`-c`, `-u`), but I'd guess that clashes with `--supress-common-lines`

Comment: They don't. Read the link.

Answer (score 3):

`vimdiff` worked great for me in 'MINGW64' [mintty 2.0.3(x86_64-pc-msys © 2015 by Andy Koppe) terminal that installed with my Vagrant install following [VaryingVagrantVagrants instructions](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/installation/).]

`Ctrl+f` to navigate forward; 
`Ctrl+b` to navigate backward/up
`:q-Enter` and again `:q-Enter` (to close the 2nd file if you've compared two files as below.)

[image: ![viminfo output example]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ1f8.png)

Arrow keys also function as well as your mouse-wheel; just be patient to let it finish loading... and you can control the color scheme in your 'MINGW64' window options as well as the `.minttyrc` file ([see here for more info](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV_bDqg_nkAhUOvJ4KHaaNDfkQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmintty%2Fmintty%2Fwiki%2FTips&usg=AOvVaw2kZxseI7QITmmprHhUkH3o)):

[image: ![MINGW64/mintty options]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qite9.png)  I made my cursor orange, blinking, so it's easier to locate.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ1f8.png):

Answer (score 0):

If you want context, you can pipe the (unsuppressed) output of sdiff (or diff -y) through egrep with before (-B) and after (-A) context:

```
sdiff -H -t file1 file2 | egrep -B1 -A1 '^.{64}[^ ]'
```

The -t and the .{64} are there to get to the midway point of the default 130 character width (expanding tabs in the output so they don't mess up the count). You can specify a shorter width, but you'd have to adjust that offset accordingly:

```
sdiff -H -w 80 -t file1 file2 | egrep -B1 -A1 '^.{39}[^ ]'
```

Comment: I mentioned the grep solution in my answer but a regex is too slow.