# Fast file comparison that displays results side by side with structure understanding (a la total commander in windows)

Tags: diff, file-comparison, vimdiff, rdiff

Is there a way/tool to show differences between two files side by side only highlighting differences in a similar way `kdiff3` does that but with a tool that is reasonably fast?A similar question was asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458834/side-by-side-diff-of-large-files) almost 6 years ago but no useful answers given. Even better a tool that understands data structure such as `csv`? I often deal with data files that might differ in a single column by a sign only or format of the number and for this purpose `diff` is quite useless. `kdiff3` shows the data like this:
[image]

Which immediately tells you what is different between the data files. It not only shows you that the whole line is different but also what is different. But, `kdiff3` is insanely inefficient, comparing 2 17 MB files takes 10 minutes which is beyond ridiculous. (I once tried something called total commander on windows which has this function and its comparing efficiency blew my mind). Being aware of data structure and showing only the different fields would be a huge advantage but all `csv` comparators that I found cannot deal with a situation that one of the files has different number of columns (say you add a column to your data) and they can only compare the same structure and so i am good with the `kdiff3` or `total commander` style approach.
I tried `vimdiff` --- says it cannot run diff on the files, `meld` --- slow and in the end does nothing, icdiff -- slow, etc.

Just as comparison and an illustration what i am looking for, i reached to a virtual machine compared the same two files with `total commander` (over network connection) and in 2 seconds (compared to 10 minutes of `kdiff3` on local ssd), i got:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`kdiff3` hasn't seen an update in 10 years¹; I don't think you really want to be using that; if that style of UI is what you're after, `meld` is probably more what you want. Anyways, you already tried that; I really can't reproduce the slowness, I tried with two similarly sized files with around 1500 changes, and it takes about 12 s to give the comparison you need. So, maybe your versions of these softwares are just *really really* old? I can't reproduce your level of slowness, even when I run at a high `nice`ness level with `stress` utilizing all my CPU cores.

If you primarily need fast: try (works *outside* of git repos!) `git diff --word-diff=color fileA.txt fileB.txt`.

Regarding structure:

Maybe you'd actually be best served with a tool that does *not* try to compare the two text files line-by-line, but with a tool that simply reads both CSVs and just outputs the differing records. But that would go into (short, but) very application-specific scripting, and would leave the scope of your question.

---

¹ it's being continued as part of KDE Gear, but your screenshot doesn't look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta)? It's quite closely coupled to git, but it can also be used to compare files outside of git.